# Attribute list in eglCreateContext

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm looking at the [android ndk](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html) opengl es example.   Anyway, it has the lines in there:

```
int[] attrib_list = {EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2, EGL10.EGL_NONE };
EGLContext context = egl.eglCreateContext(display, eglConfig, EGL10.EGL_NO_CONTEXT, attrib_list);
```

Where EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION is defined as:

```
private static int EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION = 0x3098;
```

I've been going over the [API for that call](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/eglCreateContext.xml), and it says that the last parameter is for the attributes list.  But I can't seem to find anything that actually gives attributes you might want to put in there, or even explain the two attributes that the example puts in there.  Can anyone tell me what these attributes mean?  (Or better yet, also point me to some documentation that explains it).

Thank you

Edit:  I just realised that a bit of context would help.  The particular sample is in samples/hello-gl2.  The file is in the view class, in particular, the ContextFactory static class.

Comment: I haven't found 'proper' information either but I've concluded parameters are given in two. First the attribute id you're assigning value to and then the value. In this case you're telling context client version should be 2. Why last value is always EGL10.EGL_NONE is all creek to me. Anyway, here's one [link](http://gdc2011-android-opengl.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/com/example/gdc11/MultisampleConfigChooser.java) that gave some insight to this topic once I read it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the [spec](http://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/specs/eglspec.1.4.20110406.pdf), page 43:

> `attrib list` may be `NULL` or empty
>   (first attribute is `EGL_NONE`), in
>   which case attributes assume their
>   default values as described below.
>
> `EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION`
>   determines which version of an OpenGL
>   ES context to create. An attribute
>   value of `1` specifies creation of an
>   OpenGL ES 1.x context. An attribute
>   value of `2` specifies creation of an
>   OpenGL ES 2.x context. The default
>   value for `EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION`
>   is `1`.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you.  Although how did they know to set it to 0x3098, is this just something specific to android?  Thank you.

Comment: @Lief: I imagine they took it from the [official include file](http://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/api/EGL/egl.h).

Comment: @genpfault It's odd though that they wouldn't include the constant in their Java-wrapped constants class, `android.opengl.EGL14`.