# Can I choose the OpenGL version my Android app uses at runtime?

Tags: android, mobile, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Does Android support being able to choose which version of OpenGLES at runtime?

Say I want to run my game on an old Android device that supports only 1.1 and a new Android device that has 2.0. Can I detect and then choose which version of OpenGLES to instantiate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You sure can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930274/atribute-list-in-eglcreatecontext/5930935#5930935).

Answer (score 0):

Might android:glEsVersion work as well from the Manifest?

I use this to target 1.1..

```
<uses-feature android:required="true" android:glEsVersion="0x00010001" />
```

Or is the question more like, I want to write code that can use either version and change the code being used at runtime...

Comment: the decision is to be made at runtime.