# Initializing OpenGL context in background thread

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, rendering

So I ran into a bit of a difficulty tackling the problem of offscreen rendering in android and can't find a solution to it. Please keep in mind that I'm a total newbi in all OpenGL related things, so I apologize in advance if I make any false statements.

The goal of this android process is to render stuff onto a bitmap in a background thread without the user seeing it (thus offscreen rendering). The library I use to render this stuff requires for me to set up an OpenGL context manually before I can use the utility render methods. I need to load the bitmap into a OpenGL texture (created by GLES20.glGenTextures(..)) after initializing the OpenGL context and binding it to the thread. I can't get into details about the library though.

The problem: I don't know how to set up an OpenGL context in android without using GLSurfaceView and every search for it redirects me to some kind of solution based on exactly this SurfaceView. So I need a starting point to figure out how to make calls to GLES20 valid in the background thread.

What I know is, that I need to use the methods provided by EGL14 to set it up:

```
eglCreateContext(...);
eglMakeCurrent(...);
eglInitialize(...);
```

But because the documentation is kind of non existent I have trouble figuring out what parameters to use, or even in which combination/order to use them.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Just to clarify, I'm not against solutions based on GLSurfaceView, but as I understand it, they all need to be onscreen, which I absolutely can't do.

---

EDIT 2:

So after digging some more I stumbled across something looking pretty decent:

```
mEgl = (EGL10) EGLContext.getEGL();

mEglDisplay = mEgl.eglGetDisplay(EGL10.EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);

if (mEglDisplay == EGL10.EGL_NO_DISPLAY)
    throw new RuntimeException("Error: eglGetDisplay() Failed "
            + GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(mEgl.eglGetError()));

int[] version = new int[2];

if (!mEgl.eglInitialize(mEglDisplay, version))
    throw new RuntimeException("Error: eglInitialize() Failed "
            + GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(mEgl.eglGetError()));

maEGLconfigs = new EGLConfig[1];

int[] configsCount = new int[1];
int[] configSpec = new int[]
        {
                EGL10.EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
                EGL10.EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
                EGL10.EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
                EGL10.EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
                EGL10.EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8,
                EGL10.EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 0,
                EGL10.EGL_STENCIL_SIZE, 0,
                EGL10.EGL_NONE
        };
if ((!mEgl.eglChooseConfig(mEglDisplay, configSpec, maEGLconfigs, 1, configsCount)) || (configsCount[0] == 0))
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error: eglChooseConfig() Failed "
            + GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(mEgl.eglGetError()));

if (maEGLconfigs[0] == null)
    throw new RuntimeException("Error: eglConfig() not Initialized");

int[] attrib_list = {EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2, EGL10.EGL_NONE};

mEglContext = mEgl.eglCreateContext(mEglDisplay, maEGLconfigs[0], EGL10.EGL_NO_CONTEXT, attrib_list);
```

The next call then would be:

```
final int[] textureHandle = {0};
GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureHandle, 0);
```

But textureHandle[0] is still 0. Also it prints an error to the console:

```
E/libEGL: call to OpenGL ES API with no current context
```

So if we ignore the problem, that the code uses the old EGL10 methods, it still doesn't work properly. What am I missing here?

Comment: I am not sure if creating a context should be in a class such as EGL14. The context is usually generated with a property indicating which version to use. After it you use the corresponding API. Could you check from another question egl.eglCreateContext. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930274/attribute-list-in-eglcreatecontext

Comment: You are missing a call to eglCreateSurface and eglMakeCurrent() functions. Before creating a rendering context you must create a surface, and then after creating a rendering context, you must make it current.

Comment: @MaticOblak I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. At the very bottom of my example I do exactly what you said (at least I think so looking at the link you provided).

Ah I see now that you wrote about the original post without the edit.
Yes, you are correct. I just used the examples EGL14.egl....() to show which class the method belongs to. I didn't mean to imply, that they are static methods to use. I'll edit my question to avoid misunderstandings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function below sets up OpenGL ES 1.x compatible rendering context. You can modify attrib list for the create context function to create an OpenGL ES 2.x compatible rendering context

```
void initializeEGL() {
    //get access to the EGL object, so that we can
    //initialize EGL
    mEGL = (EGL10) EGLContext.getEGL();

    //initialize display
    mDisplay = mEGL.eglGetDisplay(EGL11.EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
    if(mDisplay == EGL11.EGL_NO_DISPLAY)
    {
        Log.e("SimpleGLView", "Unable to get access to Native Display");
    }

    int[] version = new int[2];
    boolean success = mEGL.eglInitialize(mDisplay, version);
    if(!success) {
        int error = mEGL.eglGetError();
        switch(error) {
        case EGL11.EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED:
            Log.e("SimpleGLView", "Unable to initialize the EGL sub-system");
            break;
        case EGL11.EGL_BAD_DISPLAY:
            Log.e("SimpleGLView", "Display not valid");
            break;
        }
        return;
        }

    int[] mConfigSpec = {   EGL11.EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
                                EGL11.EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
                                EGL11.EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
                                EGL11.EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16,
                                EGL11.EGL_STENCIL_SIZE, 8,
                                EGL11.EGL_NONE };
    EGLConfig[] configs = new EGLConfig[1];
    int[] num_config = new int[1];

    success = mEGL.eglChooseConfig(mDisplay, mConfigSpec, configs, 1, num_config);
    if(success) {
        Log.i("SimpleGLView", "Successfully acquired a surface configuration");
        return;
    }

    mConfig = configs[0];

    mSurface = mEGL.eglCreateWindowSurface(mDisplay,mConfig, holder, null);
    if(mSurface == EGL11.EGL_NO_SURFACE) {
        Log.e("SimpleGLView", "Unable to create surface");
        int error = mEGL.eglGetError();
        switch(error) {
        case EGL11.EGL_BAD_CONFIG:
            Log.e("SimpleGLView", "Invalid configuration selected");
            break;
        case EGL11.EGL_BAD_NATIVE_WINDOW:
            Log.e("SimpleGLView", "Bad native window used");
            break;
        case EGL11.EGL_BAD_ALLOC:
            Log.e("SimpleGLView", "Not enough resources to create a surface");
            break;
        }
        return;
    }

    mContext = mEGL.eglCreateContext(mDisplay, mConfig, EGL11.EGL_NO_CONTEXT, null);
    if(mContext == null) {
        Log.i("SimpleGLView", "Create Context failed");
        return;
    }

    success = mEGL.eglMakeCurrent(mDisplay, mSurface, mSurface, mContext);
    if(success) {
        Log.i("SimpleGLView", "Made current");
    }
}
```

Comment: The snippet beginning at line 35 of the code seems kind of strange to me. Why would I want to call return if I successfully chose a config? 
Doing this would'nt create a valid context for the thread, since mEGL.eglMakeCurrent(...) won't get called, or am I missing something here?

Comment: Anyway I found a way to make it work for my purposes, your code helped me a lot, thanks!
I'll accept your answer and post my edited version of it as an answer as soon as I'm finished and satisfied with it

Comment: You are right, that return is not required. Not sure how that got in :). 
Thanks for correcting the mistake.

Comment: Little update: Sadly I can't upgrade to EGL20 because the library I have to use apparently doesn't support it. Well it works, so that's that.
Thanks again :)